# Sharing a data base in local network VisualBasic.Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, ado.net, wcf-data-services

I have created an application using Visual Basic .NET, the application use an access data base  which must be shared in server of a local network.

The problem is when i run the application in a client machine (connected to the network) I can't connect to the data base.In the same machine the connection work  wich it's not the case when I change the location of the base to: `Data Source="serverIPAdress/DataBase.mdb"`

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like `\\server\network_share\database.mdb`? Why don't you use SQL Express if you need network access. Access is not fun at all when shared across a network (not that it's that good for local scenarios either).

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the location that the database is at is accessible to the entire network. Can you on the client machine open windows explorer and see the database? If so try using that path in the data source.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do, is take the path you are placing in your DataSource="**YOURPATHHERE**" string, and do Start -> Run on the clients machine and paste the path in there. If this opens the Access Database you know you are at least looking in the right place and have access to the file. The other thing you will want to check is that the .mdb file isn't write protected, this will cause a problem. If you are running on a network where you have a central server, I would recommend using SQL Express, or if you need a flat database file SQL Server CE. Either way I would loose the Access DB.